# flutter debugger does not stop on breakpoints

Tags: debugging, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

every time I want to debug my flutter project 
the debugger does not stop on the breakpoints like there are no breakpoints 
even so the uncached exception and all exceptions bottoms in the debugger are working

my

> launch.json

file

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "Flutter",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "program": "lib/main.dart",
        "args": [
            "--debug",
            "dev"
        ],
    }]
}
```

I tried the default launch.json configurations but it's didn't work

```
{
        "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code and we can get a log and dig into this. Generally this should just work, so if you're not doing anything silly then this is probably a bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just import developer package in the intended file
import 'dart: developer' as dev;

Then use it as a breakpoint; as we use in javascript

dev.debugger();   // wherever you want to stop

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? This is a complete hack and not an answer to how to get breakpoints working.

Comment: Not intended as criticism of the answer BTW. It's great to have this tool in the toolbox. More a criticism of whoever accepted it as *the* answer. I would like regular breakpoints to work, which is what this question was about. And this answer is not the answer to that question. This should probably have been a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: I somewhat agree with @StijndeWitt, how is this acceptable?

Comment: While not the answer, it IS a workaround - one that's helping me now in 2023.

Answer (score 2):

I found that opening a symlink to my project in vscode broke the breakpoints. Opening the real path fixed it.

- Ubuntu 20 LTS
- VS Code 1.73.1
- Flutter 3.3.9